# Why is tailwind not applying md:bottom-2 in an absolute positioning setup?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have a problem where a breakpoint-selected position class isn't being added. I'm trying to move a box (a menu dropdown, in real life) from bottom left to top right of its parent element, based on the screen breakpoint.

I've set up a [tailwind play here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rUfjyaiNIu), where if you drag the width of the viewport you should see a grey box moving left to right. It should be moving diagonally (to the location of the other origin box) but for some reason is moving only horizontally.

```html
<div class="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center">
  <p class="md:hidden">sm or below</p>
  <p class="hidden md:block">md or above</p>
  <div class="relative size-48 bg-blue-500">
    <div class="absolute right-2 top-2 z-10 size-20 bg-slate-500 md:bottom-2 md:left-2">argh</div>
    <div class="z-5 absolute right-2 top-2 size-20 bg-orange-500">correct sm</div>
    <div class="z-5 absolute bottom-2 left-2 size-20 bg-orange-500">correct md</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: correct place when sm and below]
[image: what it looks like in md and above]